# Laravel validate request filter field with dot (period) in field name

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-7, request-validation

Here is to validate form request in laravel, request contains filter and field name in the filter has period(dot) present.

**Sample Request url**

...?filter[entity.abc][]='value'

Here entity.abc is actually a string, but laravel considers it to be array of object,  when rule is given for 'filter.entity.abc'

```
filter:[
    [entity]: [ {abc:'value'}]
      ]
```

which is actually

```
filter:[
   [entity.abc]:['value']
]
```

So we need to make regex for second dot, which equivalents to:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'filter.entity\.abc' => ['bail', 'sometimes', 'array'],
        'filter.entity\.abc' => ['uuid']
    ];
}
```

Above always retuns true,even when invalid uuid is present

Comment: Can you use an `_` or `-` instead of a `.`? Laravel uses "dot-notation" for a bunch of things, like nested form fields for Validation, etc etc. While the `.` may be valid, it goes against the framework you're using. Also, you can't have an array with the same key twice, it would need to be `filter.entity\.abc' => ['bail', 'sometimes', 'array', 'uuid']`

Comment: Thanks @TimLewis for highlighting this, it works.                                                         return [
        'filter.entity\.abc' => ['bail', 'sometimes', 'array'],
        'filter.entity\.abc.*' => ['uuid']
    ];

Answer (score 0):

why not modify your request like this?

```
...?filter[entity][abc][]='value'
```

Edit:

You can use custom validation in laravel where you can deconstruct the parameters and check the values manually

Laravel Custom Validation
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation

Comment: filter key is entity.abc here, not entity array and abc as a key.